# Distinct on Group By doesn't work in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, distinct

My problem is how I should use `distint()` in a way to remove/ignore the duplicates of rows in the database based on the value of one column. So here is my scenario.

I have a database as `test_db` with the following data:

```
values_list = [
    {'tweet_id': '1', 'retweet': '100', 'user_id': '101'},
    {'tweet_id': '2', 'retweet': '10', 'user_id': '101'},    
    {'tweet_id': '2', 'retweet': '11', 'user_id': '101'},        
    {'tweet_id': '10', 'retweet': '110', 'user_id': '102'},            
    {'tweet_id': '10', 'retweet': '110', 'user_id': '102'},                
    {'tweet_id': '110', 'retweet': '0', 'user_id': '2'},                    
]
```

I would like to sum the retweet count and tweet count for each user defined as `user_id`. My query for such a question is as follows:

```
q = select([
            test_db.columns.user_id,
            test_db.columns.tweet_id.distinct(),
            func.count(test_db.columns.retweet).label('count'),
            func.sum(cast(test_db.columns.retweet, Integer)).label('total_retweet'),
           ])
q = q.group_by(test_db.columns.user_id)
```

What I get is as following:

```
user_id     tweet_id  count  total_retweet
102         10        2      220
101         2         3      121
2           110       1      0
```

But my expected result should be something like this:

```
user_id     tweet_id  count  total_retweet
102         10        1      110
101         2         2      111
2           110       1      0
```

I am not sure how I should enforce `distinct` to get my expected results or there is another way to go about this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the logic behind choosing one or the other row where `tweet_id` equals 2 and `user_id` 101? I'd understand if the values were timestamped and you'd choose the latest etc.

Comment: As I show in the expected result, I choose the max retweet but I don't care which one is selected. I am just stuck with how distinct should work in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28090140/nested-select-using-sqlalchemy) about the nested query, I realized there is a solution to my question.

The table name in the db is `test` and here is the query in SQL format:

```
q = '''SELECT user_id, tweet_id, count(max_retweet) as count, 
                sum(max_retweet) as totat_retweet FROM 
                (SELECT tweet_id, max(cast(retweet as int)) as max_retweet, user_id FROM test
                GROUP BY user_id, tweet_id) 
            GROUP BY user_id
'''
```

So the equivalent converted solution in SQLAlchemy is as follows:

```
table = (
    select([
        func.max(test_db.columns.retweet).label('max_retweet'),
        test_db.columns.user_id,
        test_db.columns.tweet_id            
    ]).group_by(test_db.columns.user_id, test_db.columns.tweet_id)
    )

q = select([table.columns.user_id,
            table.columns.tweet_id,
            func.count(table.columns.max_retweet).label('count'),
            func.sum(table.columns.max_retweet).label('total_retweet')
             ])
q = q.group_by(table.columns.user_id)
```

But I am wondering if there is a solution with `distinct` expression or `distinct` should be always used with `count`, that's what I have always seen it used!

Any help or direction is also appreciated!

Comment: Note that `tweet_id` will end up being indeterminate.

Comment: You are absolutely right. For this example, I don't care about the content of the `tweet_id` and I can remove it.